Live USB, You Neet To Load The Kernel First
I did not find a solution to this error. Please help me with it. In addition, the message that appears at the beginning is:
error: file '/casper/vmlinuz' not found

Please tell us more: 1. Which flavour (Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server or one of the community flavours (Kubuntu ... Xubuntu)? 2. How did you create the live USB (which tool/method)? 3. Did you check with sha256sum that the download was successful, that the iso file is correct?

I'm Using Ubuntu Desktop

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour]. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Ubuntu 23.04 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

I suggest you no bother on trying to fix an issue with an EOL or End of Life system that could be unsafe if used online, and start again with a supported system such as Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Server/Desktop or flavor) or Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop/Server/flavor..  and ensure you validate ISO and write of ISO to media as those checks are quick & avoid issues such as errors like you have (do note there are other causes too, including you downloading the wrong architecture ISO for your unstated hardware that can cause this, plus other issues too, but we can support you if using a supported system)
